# Is there a simple way to add sub value to jwt token for test purpose?

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, jwt, mocking

I have a method that receives a Jwt token and then extracts the sub value. I would like to test it, and for that, I should mock a token and set a sub value. However, I'm somehow struggling to do it correctly.

Here is the method that I want to test:

```
public String getSub(JwtAuthenticationToken principal) {
    Map<String,Object> info = new HashMap<>();
    info.put("sub", principal.getTokenAttributes().get("sub"));
    return info.toString().replaceAll("\\{", "").replaceAll("\\}","").replace("sub=", "");
}
```

and that is the test I have created so far:

```
@Test
void testEndpoint() {
    JwtAuthenticationToken principal = Mockito.mock(JwtAuthenticationToken.class);
    Mockito.when(principal.getTokenAttributes()).thenReturn(jwt.getClaims());
    String sub = subExtractionService.getSub(principal);
    String test = "subValue";

    Assertions.assertEquals(test, sub);
}
```

The test doesn't work, of course, since as mentioned above, I still need to set the sub value. That's exactly my question: how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

The JWT would typically be generated outside of the application that requires it to authorize users. If you tweak the JWT on the fly you should have problems signing the data accordingly. You need to find out the code that authentifies users and creates/signs the JWT.

For your unit-test you seem to have mocked this subvalue. Assuming you would also have it at application runtime there is no issue so far.

But are you aware that JWT stands for JSON Web Token? The payload of the token is JSON, so you should use a JSON parser to properly get to your value, rather than going with a text replacement hack.